# Connect to Oracle using ROracle

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle using ROracle_1.3-1 . When I run the following commands:

```
library(ROracle)

drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(drv = drv, username='user', password='password',dbname='DB')
```

It is raised the following error:

> Error in .oci.Connect(.oci.drv(), username = username, password =
>   password,  :    ORA-24315: illegal attribute type

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: can you find "DB" in your tnsnames.ora file? does connecting using `sqlplus user/password@DB` in command line work fine?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can find DB in my tsnames.ora

Comment: The command sqlplus also worked fine

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that the package ROracle was corrupted or something like that. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it using the following commands

```
setwd("xxxxx")   # set to path of download
install.packages('ROracle_1.2-1.zip', repos = NULL)
```

The file ROracle_1.2-1.zip was previsouly downloaded from this web site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/roracle/downloads/index.html.

After that all worked fine.